# Force modal to not exceed phone screen when zoomed in?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am making this web app where the content of the page is very large (it is a map, so should be) when zooming in the things on the map becomes clear, just like when using google map etc. The things on my map i clickable, and a modal pops up with containing information about the place, the problem i encounter is that to modal is zoomed out as well to fit the outer div that contains the large map.

it is not a problem that the map exceeds the phonescreen on zoom, that is the whole point of it. But it is a problem that the appearing modal is extremly large so people need to zoom out every time they want to see a modal, and then zoom back in on the map to find the place they are looking for.

Is there a way to force the modal to be sized to the screen and not the outer div?

Some detail: I'm using angular.js for my webapp, the modal is a uibmodal from ui-bootstrap.

The map is a div inside an angular view, the div is set to be 100% width and height is forced to be width*1.45 which is the ratio format of the map. (this is done with an angular directive, that listen on screen resize event so height is fluently set to the right amount.

If i am not explaining my self clear enough try visit the live demo at http://146.185.173.50/ca3/#/home - you will see that on pc browsers zooming is not possible, but if you go to the app using a phone, zoom in and click on a place it is easy to notice the problem with the modal size.

This problem is very hard to google :o any suggestions?

**This is how the modal is activated from the html page:**

```
<span ng-click="showDialog(shop)" class="shop">{{shop.name}}</span>
```

**This is how it is launched from within angular:**

```
.controller('ShopCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $uibModal, ShopService, selectedShopFac) {
        $scope.shops = [];
        $scope.selectedShop = selectedShopFac.setSelectedShop({});
        ShopService.getShops().then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.shops = response.data;
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data.toString());
                });
        $scope.showDialog = function (shop) {
            $scope.selectedShop = selectedShopFac.setSelectedShop(shop);
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/home/shop/shop.html',
                scope: $scope
            });
        };
    })
```

**This is the directive that manages the size of "the map" (the parent div to the shops):**

```
.directive('mapDir', function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {

                var mapDiv = element;

                angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    mapDiv.height(mapDiv.width() * 1.45);

                });

                function onResize() {
                    mapDiv.height(mapDiv.width() * 1.45);
                }

                onResize();
                angular.element($window).on('resize', onResize);
            }
        };

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

So i sort of found a solution to this. (more like a "work around")

in the shop.html i added in the top:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

where the maximum-scale=1.0 forces the screen back to unzoomed state, and
now the modal fits the screen nicely as intended. Though the map is also zoomed out again which i wanted to avoid. (whatever)

In the controller i added a .closed.then which will manipulate the metatag back to zoomable state, so map again can be zoomed in. watch this:

```
$scope.showDialog = function (shop) {
            $scope.selectedShop = selectedShopFac.setSelectedShop(shop);
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/home/shop/shop.html',
                scope: $scope
            })
            .closed.then(function () {
                $window.document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes";
            });
        };
```

I tested this on my phone (chrome on android) after deploying, and it works as a charm. Though it seems NOT to be compatible on my ipad which is running an old version of chrome + safari.

Once again, this is not a 100% solution to the actual question, but it is a nice work around, that gets the job done.